# "Too many thoughts" better wording

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-request, phrase-choice

What is a better way to say "too many thoughts"?

I'm writing a post and one of my headings is

**Too Many Thoughts v. Hyper-focusing**

Comment: *Overthinking* might do.

Comment: I think this may need some more context. Are you talking about concentration problems and such? If so. that's not the same as _overthinking_.

Comment: You already know the answer: there seems to be a spectrum here, with **unfocused** on the one end and **hyper-focused** or **tunnel-vision** on the other.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your title, I’m assuming you want an antonym for being focused. If that’s the case, I would suggest ***distractions***.

So, you could say:

> Too Many Distractions vs. Hyper-focusing

Or:

> Distracted or Focused?

(I like the balance of my second suggestion.)